# How do I resolve the error below?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reportingservices-2005

I have a .rdlc report I created using vs2010.

The report has 2 parameters: location (integer) and dteo(datetime).

When I run running the report using vss reportviewer, I get following error:

**An error has occurred during report processing.
is not a valid value for Int32.
Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

I have no idea what could be causing this error and how to fix.

Thanks a lot in advance

Hello again Dearest Experts, I am providing additional information with the hope that I can get some help.

The code below is generated from the report ran on vss2010.

As you can see, there are 2 parameters, doe and location. Location is integer while doe is of date datatype. location is coming from a lookup table called Locations. Each location (integer) is associated with location_description (nvarchar)

I would be glad to provide more if needed.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I've only used reporting service years ago and I can only recall you need to set if the parameter allows null if you do not pass anything in. But that may not be the case you met, can you run it via reporting service server directly?

Comment: Hi Simon, The null thing was my initial thought as well but that's not the problem. I did run it there before and it said to enter a an int instead of text and got values. I will try again.